# Converting DNA sequence to time series in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, time-series

To investigate further DNA,I am trying to convert DNA sequence into time series data.
my current algorithm is:

```
for (i in 1:length(dnaSeq)){
    if (dnaSeq[i]=="A"){
      t[i+1]=t[i]+2  
    }
    else if(dnaSeq[i]=="G") {
      t[i+1]=t[i]+1
    }
    else if(dnaSeq[i]=="C") {
      t[i+1]=t[i]-1
    }
    else if(dnaSeq[i])=="T") {
      t[i+1]=t[i]-2
    }
  }
```

Anyone can suggest any other algorithm or more efficient one for conversion?

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve. Please clarify.

Comment: There is one core problem that makes this difficult to speed up: each time point depends on the last.

Comment: @Pascal suppose i have dna sequence of ATTCAAGTCCGCATTAAGC, i want to convert this sequence into time series which shows the trends of changing contents. but this algorithm is very stereotype and has some problems.

Answer (score 2):

First let's define some sample data

```
set.seed(15)
dnaSeq<-sample(c("A","C","G","T"), 20, replace=TRUE)
```

I'm not sure how you initialize `t[1]` so i'll ignore that value. But here's a way to recode your data

```
ncode <- c(A=2, G=1, C=-1, T=-2)
t2 <- cumsum(ncode[dnaSeq])
```

When i compare to your alogorithm, i see

```
all(t[-1] == t2)
```

So I believe this is more compact and efficient. Once you have your vector of numeric values, you may convert to time series however you like.